# Does garbage collection necessitate a larger memory footprint?

Tags: memory-management, garbage-collection, memory-footprint

Does a language that uses garbage collection necessarily have a significantly higher memory footprint than a language with manual memory management, such as C, C++ or Rust?

For context, I'm considering embedded systems, but the question's a general one

Comment: Short answer: yes, because in addition to general requirements of the memory allocator, you also need storage to track the lifetime or reference count of objects.  I wouldn't say _significantly_ though.

Comment: In regards to embedded systems, you generally want to avoid any kind of dynamic memory management that is outside of your direct control.  Generally you will build your own allocation scheme (_e.g._ memory pool / arena alloc) on top of those provided by the system and then run entirely within the bounds of your program's actual requirements.

Comment: Short answer: yes, because it is required by the 45. president of the unit states. i think this question will be flagged soon because it is opinion based. There is an generell Lore that say yes but on the other hand you might go better with an generic simple garbage collector than with manual managing. Oh and not to mention you could also do both in the same program! Each one for separate parts or one inside the other.

Comment: @Lee yes it is bordering on opinion based. That's why I added 'necessarily', which might preclude it being closed

Comment: That still not helping. It easy to show that it is possible to have less memory footprint with one garbage collected language than with one not garbage collected. (By construction both of them). So only best case for both categories is worth to compare. But for this i don't know howto choose better case as there is no proof that best cases has already developed for any of both cases.

Comment: @paddy sophisticated JVMs do not use reference counting and knowing the an object’s lifetime is not mandatory. The footprint of a traversing gc can be reduced to a single bit per object, if you wish. But since you do not want to perform a garbage collection before every object allocation, having more memory than occupied by the objects in use is required to get a reasonable performance. But well, the standard libraries for common languages like C or C++ also allocate larger chunks for higher performance…